# Create a JVM Language

Tags: java, jvm, antlr

So, for an assignment in school, I have to try to develop a **very basic** (no need to make it advanced) language that runs on the JVM. I already created a grammar with ANTLR, and I generated a parser and lexer with it. Now for the "compile to JVM bytecode" part, I am kinda lost. I looked at ASM and Jasmin, I'm going to use one of them (or any of your suggestions), but the question remains: How can I transform/translate the Abstract Syntax Tree from the generated parser to JVM bytecode... if it's possible! Thank you!

P.S: Should I use ANTLR Visitors or Listeners?

Comment: The documentation of these libraries (ASM or Jasmin) focus on how to use these libraries. You should study the [Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) first as understanding the JVM is required to make use of the code generation libraries. Note that the spec has a dedicated chapter, [§3, Compiling for the Java Virtual Machine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html) containing some practical examples. For most basic statements and expressions, a code producing visitor could be sufficient.

Comment: @Holger I will surely look at this specification, and you are right, it is kind of stupid of me to dive in to JVM bytecode without understanding most of it! Thanks!